# Cycling through a jQuery object with elements grouped together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom-manipulation

I have a set of list items that contain nested lists, sort of like this:

```
<ul class="searchselectors">
  <li class="group">Group name 1
    <ul>
      <li class="item selected">List item 1.1</li>
      <li class="item">List item 1.2</li>
      <li class="item">List item 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="group">Group name 2
    <ul>
      <li class="item">List item 2.1</li>
      <li class="item">List item 2.2</li>
      <li class="item">List item 2.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="group">Group name 3
    <ul>
      <li class="item">List item 3.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to cycle through all of the `.item` elements using up/down arrow keys (which I already have set up by using `on('keydown')` and catching key codes `38` and `40`) and set `.selected` on the next item before or after the currently selected item, wrapping around to the top/bottom as necessary.

Using `$().next()` and `$().prev()` will not work, since it will only work on **siblings**, and not on a jQuery object such as `$('.searchselectors .item')`.\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was working on the same problem but in my project I'm using [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com). In fact, the original logic was written with pure jQuery and I refactored it with Knockout. Here's a solution for your problem using jQuery:

**[Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6QN77/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/6QN77/2/)**

I didn't spend too much time cleaning up the JavaScript, but I'm leaving that to you now.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="searchselectors">
  <li class="group">Group name 1
    <ul>
      <li class="item selected">List item 1.1</li>
      <li class="item">List item 1.2</li>
      <li class="item">List item 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="group">Group name 2
    <ul>
      <li class="item">List item 2.1</li>
      <li class="item">List item 2.2</li>
      <li class="item">List item 2.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="group">Group name 3
    <ul>
      <li class="item">List item 3.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var $menu = $("#searchselectors"),
        $items = $menu.find(".item"),
        $selectedItem = $menu.find(".selected"),
        selectedIndex = $selectedItem.length - 1;

    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 40:  // down arrow
                $selectedItem.removeClass("selected");
                selectedIndex = (selectedIndex + 1) % $items.length;
                $selectedItem = $items.eq(selectedIndex).addClass("selected");
                break;
            case 38:  // up arrow
                $selectedItem.removeClass("selected");
                selectedIndex = (selectedIndex - 1) % $items.length;
                $selectedItem = $items.eq(selectedIndex).addClass("selected");
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**: My solution revolves around getting a reference to a wrapper element (`#searchselectors`) and getting all the `LI` elements marked with the CSS class `.item`. Next I get a reference to the currently selected element and its index. Finally, the code listens to the down and up arrow keys being pressed (`keydown`), decrementing if going up and incrementing if going up. Cycling is achieved via the modulus operator. The selected item's CSS class is removed and put back. The selected item reference is used for performance reasons so I don't have to write `$items.removeClass(".selected").eq(selectedIndex).addClass("selected");`

Comment: I've been trying to implement it into my solution, but for some reason it doesn't work as it does within jsFiddle, where I even brought in my own code and tested it, only for it to work. The fiddle can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/AYpe8/. I can upload the full page/js later on if needed.

Comment: Hmmm... That's interesting. Did you see any errors in the JavaScript console? I'm wondering if the jQuery can't find a specific set of elements? Yes, I'd like to see what's going on if possible.

Comment: I did not see any errors, however when I did log the contents of the variables to console, they were empty. http://lain.rustedlogic.net/projects/hp/ (Javascript can be viewed at http://lain.rustedlogic.net/projects/hp/js/app.js)

Comment: I think I know what's going on. The `$items` is being cached when you initialize the widget and call `this.bindUIActions();` for the first time. It never gets updated once the search widget receives items. Move the code that initializes the `$items` and `$selectedItem` to the `keydown` event. [See your updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYpe8/1/)

Comment: That worked. I suppose I should've noticed that in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

In my quest to provide native JS answers to those looking for it, here is @Mario j Vargas' good answer adapted in native Javascript. It only takes 2 lines of extra code.

http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/7tQSW/2/

Only putting the JS up here, HTML is the same.

```
(function () {
    var $menu = document.getElementById('searchselectors'),
        items = $menu.getElementsByClassName('item'),
        $selectedItem = $menu.getElementsByClassName('selected')[0],
        selectedIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call($selectedItem, items)+1;

    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 40:  // down arrow
                $selectedItem.className = $selectedItem.className.replace(' selected','');
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex < items.length - 1 ? selectedIndex + 1 : selectedIndex;
                $selectedItem = items[selectedIndex];
                $selectedItem.className += ' selected';
                break;
            case 38:  // up arrow
                $selectedItem.className = $selectedItem.className.replace(' selected','');
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex > 0 ? selectedIndex - 1 : selectedIndex;
                $selectedItem = items[selectedIndex];
                $selectedItem.className += ' selected';
                break;
        }
    }, false);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get all the list items with class "item" is:

```
var items = $('.item'); 

 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i]; // iterate
 }
```

And then, you can select the next item from the list

OR

you can do this

```
 if (!$().next) {
    var nextUL= $().parent.find('ul')
    iterateThruList(nextUL);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like

```
var UL = $(".searchselectors").children().length; //number of UL (group names)
```

to iterate through items.